# Drupal crud applications

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7, crud

Thanks in advance.

Learning Drupal right now as recommended by many people and I cannot get a straight answer to this question:

What are the steps to setting up a CRUD application using Drupal?

(I'll explain further. But that is the premise.)

Working on an application that will do reporting and help out a small sales company with their prospecting and data analysis. Excel right? nope. Their clients will also be needing to access some of their data live via a webapp, so there will need to be different logins with levels of access (clients will see specific data related to their account, sales people will see their accounts, and management will see everything). Here's the real kicker they would like to eventually make it into a native app for android or IOS.

Originally I was going to build it in Codeigniter... which seemed easier, but it was recommended to me that I could cut down on my workload and utilized the "services" module later to do what I am looking to get done now and in the future.

Ignoring the project, I haven't even been able to figure out how to create a form for inputing data (I was assuming "Webforms"). Have that stored to a database, and then displayed in a sortable table.

I have searched around and can't really find a guide to building a simple CRUD application using Drupal as a CMS. I am totally willing to figure out how to put it together if someone could just tell me what modules/ things I need to do.

Example (INCORRECT) 
1) Install these modules: Webform, views, CCK, Webform MySQL Views)
2) Activate the modules
3) Configure *_* to interact with a specific database Table
4) Et Cetera

In all fairness, I'm still learning how to use Drupal and Doing CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) type interactions might now be possible. If it isn't possible then I apologize for your reading all the way down.

Cheers + Happy Summer

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using Drupal 7 (which has CCK built in). Then create one or more content types for the things people will see. Install Views and use that to build the displays for each role (Views is pretty powerful). You'll need to research which node access module would help you best restrict add/edit/delete privileges.

However, you said CodeIgniter is an option (ignoring the fact that CI is not maintained anymore). Any reason why Drupal was recommended instead of another PHP framework like Silex/Yii/Symfony/ZF2/LAravel? Depending on client needs (and how flexible they are) you may find yourself fighting against how Drupal wants to do certain things.  If they eventually want to power more than a website via an API, seems like a non-Drupal solution could be better fit. (Until Drupal 8 is out and changes things up a bit)